# How to set ICON image for java.jar executable jar file

Tags: java, user-interface, jar

I have developed a game in Java made an executable jar file mygame.jar.

I now want to set an ICON image to mygame.jar so that it shows my custom image instead of usual java tea cup image.

Please don't confuse this with setting frame icon image with frame.setImageIcon("") method to set frame ICON image. I want my custom image to show up in mygame.jar desktop ICON

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.

Comment: Then how is skype , google chrome ,flv and almost  all commercial softwares displaying their own custom image as desktop icon image??

Comment: Because they are executables not `jars` :)

Comment: Oh okay I got that .Thanks for the help

Comment: Also dont forget to go through the answers below and mark the one which helps you.

Comment: @user46418 All `flv`s do have the same icon, just like jars. Only "real programs" get to have custom icons, on most operating systems. (On Windows, so do shortcuts; I don't know about the equivalent of a shortcut on other OSes)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the icon of a `.jar` file cannot be changed. The only way to set the icon is to convert it to a different form of executable. Such as `.exe` for windows, and `.app` for mac.

You can use tools such as `JarBundler` or `Appbundler` for converting to `app`, and there are a few tools for converting to `.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper like [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) for jars. Not only does it allow you to define custom icons for your java applications, it also creates `.exe`  for your java applications.

[JSmooth DOC](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html) and a [good tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/09/convert-java-jar-file-to-exe-using-jsmooth/)

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible. Not in the jar itself. You have to generate a wrapper that executes the jar, and this script will have the icon. You can try JSmooth.