# Put an icon on the jar file

Tags: java, jar, wrapper

I need to put an icon on the jar and I don't know how I can do this. Reading on google some people suggest me to use some wrapper. My question is this: Can I put an image on the jar without install this wrapper? Anyone can help me?

I mean this image:
http://it.tinypic.com/r/ngksp/8

Comment: Not sure what you mean but if you are talking about icon that the jar uses when it is executed , then it should be included in jar itself like you include .class files during packaging.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (without wrapper). Java is cross-platform language and icon format itself is often "platform dependent" - operating system is in charge of "linking icons to files business".

[Set Icon for executable Jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927509/set-icon-for-executable-jar-file)

[How to change executable jar file icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590885/how-to-change-executable-jar-file-icon)

[How to set ICON image for java.jar executable jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179705/how-to-set-icon-image-for-java-jar-executable-jar-file)